# Mismatching IDs when uploading extension to the store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I want to add OAuth to my chrome extension, I am on the step where you acquire the proper keys to put into your manifest.json.

The problem lies when I upload the zip file to the store and the ID is different from the one found on *chrome://extensions*

[image: ID Mismatch]

Comment: If your manifest.json doesn't have `"key"` value, the id generated by Chrome is simply a SHA of the directory path to your extension directory.

Comment: Oh wow thanks that fixed it! But, now I have another problem.  If I request an Auth Token, it always returns ['bad request'](https://imgur.com/a/d6yMN1B) <--pic of error--.